# Updating widget from UI make the UI freezing

Tags: android, widget

In order to refresh my widget from my app, I'm using this piece of code in an `AsyncTask`:

```
// REFRESH WIDGET
int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(MainActivity.getActivty().getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(MainActivity.getActivty().getApplication(), WidgetClass.class));
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.getActivty(),WidgetClass.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);

// Use an array and EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS instead of AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
// since it seems the onUpdate() is only fired on that:
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
MainActivity.getActivty().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This is working except that it's freezing the UI. As the process in the widget takes a bit of time, this is freezing the screen for 1/2 seconds, sometimes more, which I want to avoid.

Using this in a runnable is producing the same result.

Is there a way to update a widget from the app without freezing the UI?

Comment: Please post `getAppWidgetIDs` function

Comment: This is the native method from AppWidgetanager.java, I'm not overriding this

Comment: I thinks that's the issue. You are getting the ids from the system widget manager, If you look at the code of AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds, it uses some AppWidgetService to return the ids. Which is a heavy task I guess. You should change this approach.

Comment: I don't really know how to do otherwise, I was thinking this kind of intent was sending a signal to the widget and then this widget was running in an independant thread

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the Widget `TextView` or whole `View` which contains many layouts and views etc then you can just use `View.invalidate()`, it will refresh your Views.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is an AsyncTask call as it's getting a lot of datas from my server before updating the views itself. Also, how am I suppose to get the View id ? Especially if there is many instances of the widget?

Comment: If you have many instances of widget, then hold references of widget and when you want to update iterate over references and call update on every instance.

Comment: The thing is, some views have to remain if the server failed to get the data from the server; however invalidate() will flush everything. This is, sadly, not  working on my case...